# Unable to map SharePoint folder or access it via an Excel macro unless SharePoint is open in Internet Explorer

Tags: authentication, internet-explorer, vba, mapped-folder

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494596/excel-vba-read-from-a-closed-sharepoint-file-not-working) on Stack Overflow a while ago, but didn't get any responses so far so thought I'd try here.

Basically, I'm using an Excel macro to download a few files stored in a SharePoint folder. I'm one of the owners of this SharePoint site. If, the moment I run the macro, I have the Share Point site open in Internet Explorer - the macro will download the files OK. If I don't have it open in IE, it won't download. IE is NOT my default browser, never has been. SharePoint is in my trusted sites, always has been.

The same with mapping a SP folder - I need to open the SP site in IE before I can map it as a local drive, otherwise, I am getting an error saying I am not authenticated or don't have it in my trusted sites.

Having the site open in any other browsers makes no difference.

Would really appreciate is someone could enlighten me on what is causing this and how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you, end to end, trying to accomplish, ignoring the macro unless it plays into the overall solution? At face value, I would say you should use Power Automate flows instead (with the Data Management Gateway), but there is probably something more to this. And yes, mapping SharePoint folders, which isn't great practice, requires IE.

Comment: Thank you, @TrevorSeward, unfortunately the VBA macro to download the files is only part of my larger VBA-based solution - I am pulling data from various sources, i.e. SQL databases, SharePoint and Dynamics 365 into Excel, process the data (quite extensively, including running additional SQL queries) and then generate HTML-formatted email with the results. I'm using VBA because the data is in tabular format and I'm familiar with VBA, so I know how to make it work and work fast. Perhaps it's all possible in Flow today, but I'd need to build it from scratch, while the VBA is up and running.

Comment: I don't map SharePoint folders in my VBA, it's just something I noticed when troubleshooting this issue - the error i was getting when trying to map was consistent with the error i was getting in my VBA when trying to access the file.

Comment: The reason you're probably seeing this is that VBA, internally, will use IE (or really, mshtml) for retrieving content. So you'd need to be logged in with IE to make that connection. The alternative is to move away from this style of accessing data (it's super legacy) and move towards something like data warehouse + Power BI.

Comment: Thank you, again, I totally agree, storing an Excel file on SharePoint and downloading it inside a VBA procedure to retrieve data is far from optimal. Soon, we'll move away from SharePoint and store this data in a SQL database. OK, so I take it the behavior I am seeing is "per design" and will need to learn to live with it. Thank you very much for all your help, @TrevorSeward